# Importing .css into jsp document

Tags: java, css, jsp

How to link a css file into a jsp file. My jsp file is in /WEB-INF/Pages/connection.jsp My css file is in `/WEB-INf/Pages/style.css` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't put public+static resources in `WEB-INF` (WEB-INF is for protected resources, like JSPs)
2. Put public resources in `webapp/static` (pages is not a good names for things that aren't pages)
3. Use JSTL core url tag for URLs:

   `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/static/styles/style.css'/>">`
4. Use lowercase URLs (at least the domain and path)

Answer (score 2):

In jsp file use that tag inside the header tag,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Pages/Style.css">
```

Comment: This solution would be correct if the CSS file was placed outside the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: We cannot access outside the web-inf.

Comment: resources that need to be accessed from the client side (i.e. from the browser) cannot be done so from within the WEB-INF - the WEB-INF is not visible to the web as in the outside world. The WEB-INF can only be accessed on the server. So a server redirect to a JSP in WEB-INF will work but if a CSS is in WEB-INF and the browser requests it it will not be served.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS and JS (any client side resources CANNOT reside in the WEB-INF folder as it is not visible outside - it can only be accessed from the server.